# Getting input from QLineEdit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Someone made me a GUI but I still don't understand some stuff:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=QtWidgets.QWidget()
vbox=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
text_1=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
text_2=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
run_btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton("run")
text_3=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
def main():
    data_1=text_1.text()
    data_2=text_2.text()
    text_3.setText(str(data_1)+(data_2))
run_btn.clicked.connect(main)
vbox.addWidget(text_1)
vbox.addWidget(text_2)
vbox.addWidget(run_btn)
vbox.addWidget(text_3)
window.setLayout(vbox)
window.show()
print text_1.text()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

1. Why when I try to print what's in `text_1` I get a syntax error?

> ```
>   print text_1.text()
>              ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

2. Why after I click the run button nothing happens?

Comment: You will need to paste the full syntax error. It's difficult to tell what went wrong if we don't have this information.

Also, I ran this code and it appeared to work just fine. I think there is something wrong with your configuration.

Comment: @CraigularJoe I know the code works ... but after i add a line : 
    print text_1.text()
it give me an syntax error .... why ... i want to use whats in text_1 thats my problem i dont know how

Comment: I see now. Please do the following things:
**1.** post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will reproduce your error (show us exactly what you are doing that results in the traceback)
**2.** paste the full traceback. This will make it much easier to help answer your question.

Comment: @CraigularJoe Hey man , sry I didnt know i should do that ...here a screenshot of the program and the problem : http://prntscr.com/ee4nln
i only added the print line , the rest is like i posted on top

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the update. In the future, it would be better to edit your question so that I can see the full code sample and traceback in the question text (rather than follow a link from the comments to a screenshot). It might also be helpful to include what version of Python you're using. This is important in your case because while `print 'hi'` works in Python 2 (I am using Python 2.7 and your code works fine for me), it will not work in Python 3, which prefers `print('hi')`.

Comment: @CraigularJoe damn im stupid... im used to work in 2.7 and this is on 3.4 ..... my bad i guess :( but i still have problem with the run button ... i want it to close after you press it so the code continues and i can print text1.text() and stuff so what def it needs to take so it will just basically be an OK btn?

Comment: I think this comments section is probably not the best venue for providing debugging support. Remember, questions on Stackoverflow aren't meant to just solve a problem that you're having: they are meant as a reference for other people who might have similar problems. You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post another question once you have **1.** a single, specific question (not several questions), **2.** a minimal code sample (don't just post your entire program, **3.** done research to make sure the same question hasn't been asked before/isn't answered in docs.